# How do I HTML decode a string?

Tags: ruby

I have two strings:

```
"50's & 60's"
```

and

```
"50's &amp; 60's"
```

and they need to be a match.

Is there a way that I can do something to the string, maybe HTML decode before I compare?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML) or its synonym `CGI::unescape_html`:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::unescape_html "50's &amp; 60's" # => "50's & 60's"
```

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work with non-breaking spaces? --> `>> CGI::unescapeHTML("sdf&nbsp;sdsdf") => "sdf&nbsp;sdsdf"`

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

Hpricot("50's &amp; 60's", :xhtml_strict => true).to_plain_text # => "50's & 60's"
```

Comment: Using Hpricot is major overkill for this, and using a side-effect of the module's primary purpose, which is XML/HTML parsing.

Comment: they way you can do things in ruby are different, I don't know of the author already using that gems However this is just another possible solution rather than using cgi gem. No pressure, just alternative. And can't agree with you more.